# Laptop powers off if low on battery

Tags: power-management, shutdown, battery

I noticed this started to happen when I installed Ubuntu on separate partition. When it reaches low battery level, instead of prompting that battery is low, it just powers off (the same way you would hold a power button long enough for it to instantly shut down). The same thing is happening on Windows as-well (another partition). I can't find solution for this and it just kills me inside when it powers off like this, how can I fix this?

Laptop: Asus X552CL
Year bought: 2014
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can you please add the laptop model and year you bought it. Additionally we would need the Ubuntu version you are using.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado fixed in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a new battery if this is occurring on both Windows and Linux.